# PyInstaller exe returning error on a Tkinter script

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a simple applet built using the standard python library with a Tkinter GUI through Pyinstaller for distribution. PyInstaller compiles (correct term?) it fine, but when I open the exe, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth__tkinter.py", line 28, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: Tcl data directory "/var/folders/sj/r0yyz8393ld2xrd_wf65bwxr0000gn/T/_MEIDeFnFy/tcl" not found.
[67821] Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I've tried tweaking my compile settings such as adding `--hidden-import tkinter` to no avail.

Here's the script:

```
import math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog as sd

grades = []

def convert(grades):
    #long function here

def get_num_classes():
    while True:
        try:
            global num_classes
            num_classes =  sd.askinteger("number of classes", "Number of classes: ")
            return num_classes
        except ValueError:
            print('Try again')

def get_current():
    global current_gpa
    current_gpa = sd.askfloat("current gpa", "Current GPA: ")
    return current_gpa

def grade_append():
    y = 0
    while y < num_classes:
        grade = sd.askstring("grade", "Letter Grade: ")
        grade = grade.upper()
        grades.append(grade)
        y = y+1

def calculate(grade_points, current_gpa, classes):
    global cum_gpa
    gpa = grade_points / classes
    cum_gpa = (gpa + current_gpa) / 2
    return cum_gpa

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("GPA Calculator")
root.geometry("225x50")

get_num_classes()

get_current()

grade_append()

total_points = convert(grades)

calculate(total_points, current_gpa, num_classes)
cum_gpa = round(cum_gpa, 2)

print(cum_gpa)
print(grades)

w = tk.Label(root, text="Your new cumulative GPA is %s" % (cum_gpa))
w.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the version of pyinstaller? what command are you using to do the packaging? and where do you run the exe ?

Comment: @DavidSidarous 1. 3.4 2. ```pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import tkinter``` I said that above. 3. In the default dist folder it packages to in the project master folder.

Comment: is tkinter updated to the latest version?

Comment: @DavidSidarous Should be, I installed it within the past two weeks.

Comment: Just one more check, are you packaging in the same OS as target environment?
which seems to be OS X ?

Comment: @DavidSidarous I believe so. I'm not familar with pyinstaller, this is my first foray, but I am packaging and running it on the same system.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems to be a known problem for using `--onefile` on OS X

Try this from the directory where you have the python script

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk':'tk' --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl':'tcl' your_script.py
```

This solution was suggested in the open issue [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1350#issuecomment-445515792)

Answer (score 2):

This is my answer I think that this will help you :

`pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk':'tk' --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl':'tcl' your_script.py`

or for no console code is :

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk':'tk' --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl':'tcl' your_script.py`