# Tcl/Tk improperly installed error when using Auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a EXE file using auto-py-to-exe (pyinstaller). My script implements tkinter to create a GUI. However, when I run pyinstaller, this error message appears.

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk' (most likely due to a circular import)
> 975818 ERROR: Tcl/Tk improperly installed on this system..

I have viewed solutions however none of them are working for me.
I found this page to be helpful:
[PyInstaller exe returning error on a Tkinter script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503113/pyinstaller-exe-returning-error-on-a-tkinter-script)

However, I cannot find the file locations on my computer and do not think they exist.

> binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk':'tk'
> --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl':'tcl' your_script.py

I did find a script called tcl_Tk.py and it is associated with hooks
I read that script and found this:

> ## TODO Shouldn't these be fatal exceptions?

```
if not tcl_root:
    logger.error('Tcl/Tk improperly installed on this system.')
    return []
if not os.path.isdir(tcl_root):
    logger.error('Tcl data directory "%s" not found.', tcl_root)
    return []
if not os.path.isdir(tk_root):
    logger.error('Tk data directory "%s" not found.', tk_root)
    return []
```

I do not have tk_root or Tcl_root installed. And have been using tkinter from Anaconda Navigator (anaconda3) environment

Other background information:
I am using Spyder(3.8) as my IDE

Imports:

> import tkinter as tk,
> import pandas as pd,
> from PIL import Image, ImageTk,
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt,
> plt.style.use('ggplot')

Any solutions how I can get this to work?